# How to center align a "pre-scrollable" class in bootstrap?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to center a pre-scrollable div class but it keeps pulling left.

I tried the text-center class

```
<div class="border pre-scrollable text-center" id='therapist-display'>
```

I also tried targeting it with CSS

```
#therapist-display
        {
            border-style: solid;
            background: white;
            height:230px;
            width: 650px;
            text-center;
        }
```

However nothing has worked.

Comment: Did you try putting it in a parent div with `width: 100%` and center align that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `margin: auto` center aligns the given div if that is what you are looking for.
https://jsfiddle.net/8Lcae7nb/